# Combining inheritance with modules for NodeJS Tesla API project

Tags: javascript, node.js, module

I'm trying to make a simple NodeJS application using express and request modules. In this case, I'm trying to implement the strategy design pattern to clean up the different HTTP requests that are made throughout the application. My idea is to have an **Options** class as the base class, and then have accessToken, getVehicleID, getVehicleStatus, etc. extend this base class, only overriding the things that necessary items (i.e. different body contents, add to the headers, change method from 'POST' to 'GET', etc.). However I'm not sure if this is the correct way as I'm fairly new to JS, and right now am getting the error 'Options is not defined'. Any help would be appreciated! Would love to have a more scalable design.

My Options class looks as follows:

```
Options = (function() {

  function construct() { 
    var self = this;
    var requestURL = '';
    var requestMethod = '';
    var requestHeaders = {};
    var requestBody = {};
  };
   /**
   * Modify request type (i.e. GET, POST, etc.)
   */
  construct.prototype.modifyRequestMethod = function() {
    throw new Error('You have to implement the method doSomething!');
 }

  /**
   * Modify URL
   */
  construct.prototype.modifyUrl = function() {
    throw new Error('You have to implement the method doSomething!');
 }

 /**
  * Modify the request headers
  */
 construct.prototype.modifyHeaders = function() {
    throw new Error('You have to implement the method doSomething!');
  }

  /**
   * Modify the request body
   */
  construct.prototype.modifyBody = function(){
    throw new Error('You have to implement the method doSomething!');
  }

  construct.prototype.updateOptions = function() {
    modifyRequestMethod();
    modifyUrl();
    modifyHeaders();
    modifyBody()
  }

  construct.prototype.returnOptions = function() {
  return {
    url: this.requestURL,
    method: this.requestMethod,
    json: true,
    headers: this.requestHeaders,
    gzip: true,
    body: this.requestBody 
  };
}

  return construct;  

})();
```

And one of the derived classes (accessToken would be):

```
accessToken = (function(){

    function construct() {
        console.log("Child");
        Options.apply(this, arguments);
        updateOptions();
        returnOptions();
    }


    construct.prototype.modifyRequestMethod = function() {
        this.requestMethod = 'POST';
 }

    construct.prototype.modifyUrl = function() {
        this.requestURL = 'https://owner-api.teslamotors.com/oauth/token';
 }

    construct.prototype.modifyHeaders = function() {
        this.requestHeaders = {
        "x-tesla-user-agent": "TeslaApp/3.4.4-350/fad4a582e/android/8.1.0",
        "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 8.1.0; Pixel XL Build/OPM4.171019.021.D1; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/68.0.3440.91 Mobile Safari/537.36",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "charset": "utf-8"
      }
  }

    construct.prototype.modifyBody = function(){
        this.requestBody = {
        "grant_type": 'password',
        "client_id": '81527cff06843c8634fdc09e8ac0abefb46ac849f38fe1e431c2ef2106796384',
        "client_secret": 'c7257eb71a564034f9419ee651c7d0e5f7aa6bfbd18bafb5c5c033b093bb2fa3',
        "email": 'myEmail',
        "password": 'myPassword'
      };
  }

  return construct;


})();
```

And then in the main application app.js:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
var path = require("path");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var rp = require('request-promise');
const port = 3000;
var firstRequest = require('./helper/accessToken.js');


app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));
app.set("view engine", "ejs");

let firstRequest = new accessToken();
var myaccessToken;

app.get("/", async(req, resp) => {

  firstRequest.updateOptions();
  const first_response = await rp(firstRequest.returnOptions());
  myaccessToken = (JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(first_response))).access_token;

});


app.listen(port, () => {console.log('Example app listening on port ${port}!') } )
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to EXPORT `Options` so that you can REQUIRE it in your new file

For example, in `Options.js`

```
var Options = ...
module.exports = Options
```

Then, in `accessToken.js` or `app.js`:

```
var Options = require("./Options.js")
```